# Choosing where to install Django project

Tags: python, django

I know that django-admin.py startproject whateveryourfolderis would install your project

But this create the project within the "django/bin" folder.  If I want to create the project somewhere eles (c:/whatever.  What is the correct command?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using windows, but the behaviour I see is that `django-admin.py startproject <name>` creates a directory called `<name>` just under the current directory. Probably you just need to change to the directory where you want the project to be created.

Comment: @jcollado: That is also the behaviour under windows.

Comment: Seems you changed working directory to where your Django is installed (like c:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\Django\bin) to be able to call `django-admin.py`. Instead you should go to the directory with your future Django project (c:\whatever) and call `django-admin.py` using full path (`c:\Python2.7\lib\site-packages\Django\bin\django-admin.py`);

Comment: I did not want to install Django in the site-packages directory.  When I did the command "import django" it automatically placed it there.

Answer (score 1):

I see what your issue might be here.

In order to use django within your system, you must navigate to the bin directory to execute the django-admin command.

You do not need to do this. You must setup an environment path pointing to your site-packages folder in your python directory.

You may also add a path pointing to the django/bin directory - therefore within the command prompt, at any point you may type 'django-admin.py' and invoke its methods.

How to define an Environment Setting:
http://support.tabs3.com/main/R10463.htm

E.g. I would add the path 'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\'

That should solve your problem.

Comment: I did what I said.  I went into the "Change my enviroment variables. There was already a Django variable that points to "C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\" so I changed that to 'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\' then I go to the command prompt and type in django-admin.py and it doesnt regonize the command.

Comment: Okay, instead of changing the old path, you can add another. Additionally - Does that path point to your django installation. Is it the correct version of python?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7, not 3 so it should be the right version. The original path are missing the django/bin folder so I would say it's not the right path?  Also I just did something, I'm not sure if it's the right practice but I moved my project folder outside of the django folder and it still seems to work. Is it ok to do this?

Comment: Yes you can move the project.
If you are running python 2.7 your path would look more like `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\`. Just make sure the path exists before you add it to your site variables. It will work once you've done that.

Comment: @Sam Mitchell how did you "install" django?

Comment: Glycerine - yes that's what I have.

Comment: Ashwoods - I install it by  doing the "setup.py install" then import django.

Comment: @SamMitchell - Do this. Edit your question, add the target python installation, your current platform (windows etc...). What commands you are typing into your command prompt and anything you feel of which could provide feedback. There is obviously elves at work here...

Comment: I got it to work, I actually need to use this path "C:\Python27\Scripts" instead.  I wonder if the newer version of Django changed the path to this instead? :/ wasted hours on this.